# Python Tkinter Password Box - How to make it similar to a bash password prompt where the length is hidden?

Tags: python, tkinter, passwords, tkinter-entry

I've made a tkinter password Entry such as:

```
passwordEntry = Entry(app, show="*")
```

I'd like to do away with the asterisks and make it completely anonymous so others next to you can't even see the length of your password.

Comment: Use the getpass() function, something like getpass.getuser() & getpass.getpass() I think.  It doesn't show anything,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the foreground and background to the same color, all they will see is spaces, and I bet it would be almost impossible for them to count the spaces.

Or, just don't use an entry widget. Use some other widget (Label, Frame, Canvas) and some bindings on `<Key>` to keep track of what they typed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm completely okay with the colors matching up. This isn't something meant to be insanely secure and the asterisks are probably enough but I wanted to take just one extra step.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
passwordEntry = Entry(app, show=" ")
```

Not the best option but just popped into my head, less coding aswell!